# omit a div if its null

Tags: php, html

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="restinfoinn">
  <div id="resthead">Purpose</div>
  <div id="restcontstitle2"><?php echo $row_pages_here['purpose']; ?></div>
</div>
```

I want it to be omitted if the value of purpose is empty/null. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php if (!empty($row_pages_here['purpose'])) : ?>
<div id="restinfoinn">
  <div id="resthead">Purpose</div>
  <div id="restcontstitle2"><?php echo $row_pages_here['purpose']; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But i think it would be better to print the empty div and deal with the design in CSS

Answer (score 3):

This is really basic. You just need to do an IF check on top.

```
<?php if (!empty($row_pages_here['purpose'])) : ?>
    <div id="restinfoinn">
      <div id="resthead">Purpose</div>
      <div id="restcontstitle2"><?php echo $row_pages_here['purpose']; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Have a look at [alternative control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: I was looking for the hidden catch in the question ^_^